# Mavensmate : [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: mavensmate

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of Error.
I cannot update any project to Salesforce server from Mavensmate.

I have tried the following on mavensmate but each one give me same error :

- Metadata > Update Project Metadata Index
- Utilities > Refresh Apex Symbols Tables for this project
- Utilities > Reset Metadata container

I really don't understand how did that happened everything was working fine and suddenly it stopped working...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked in an alternative forum - https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate/issues

Comment: Ok..I posted this issue over there too but since this is Salesforce related I think the answer should be posted here too... https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/493#issuecomment-134538119)  using custom URL solves this. For me switching to different country VPN also solved it.

Looks like regional (dns?) routing issue inside salesforce cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I guess sfdc has changed something. For me the issue was only on Dev orgs related workspaces , sandboxes surprisingly were not effected.