# Connection Reset errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is anyone else getting Connection Reset errors when trying to connect with Eclipse? I started having issues Sunday and received a call from my colleague in Montreal regarding the same issue, we have 3 dev instances and a production instance, all on NA server ranges, and we are unable to connect to any of them from the API. Issue affect both Eclipse and Apex Dataloader. I don't think the issue is related to any code we have deployed because the instances don't contain a lot of common code.  Any ideas how we can resolve this would be very helpful?  Thanks

Comment: We had the same issue. Look here:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89193/force-com-ide-eclipse-connection-issues

Comment: Could this be related? (Mavensmate) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89076/mavensmate-errno-54-connection-reset-by-peer/